# Fully Generic/Dynamic List/table generation from JSON Data using JavaScript

Tags: json, list, parsing, templates, dynamic

I'm working on a generic front end for `SQL` queries in my application, and would like to offer a preview feature that present query results.

Query results are returned in `JSON` format from a web service, and the `JSON` layout is of course completely different from query to query.

Result should be presented in a fully dynamic way, and look something like this:

```
Column 1    Column 2    Column 3  
aaaaaaa     bbbbbbbb    ccccccc
.
.
.
```

Both column headers (from json key) and row content (from json value) should be generated in code, with or without the use of template libraries.

Any suggestions on what is the easiest and/or most efficient approach?

Comment: Did my answer help you at all? If it did you may want to pick it as the answer to the question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```
function createTableFromJson(json){
    var table = "<table><tr>";
    $.each(json.results[0], function(key, value){
        table+= "<th>" + key + "</th>";
    });
    table += "</tr>";
    $.each(json.results, function(key, value){
        table +="<tr>";
        $.each(value, function(k,v){
            table += "<td>" + v + "</td>";
        });
        table +="</tr>";
    });
    table += "</table>";
    return table;
}
```

Check out [this](http://jsfiddle.net/adcQZ/2/) jsfiddle for a complete example.